# Gennymotion unable to load virtualbox engines

Tags: 14.04, grub2, virtualbox, android

When I start gennymotion this is the error message shown:

> Unable to load VirtualBox engine.
>   Make sure that it is properly installed before starting Genymotion.
>   For more information, please refer to https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#vbox
>   Genymotion log archive has been saved in: /home/arka/genymotion-log.zip
>   Please contact Genymotion support for more help.

I have virtual box installed on my machine.

Please provide step by step instructions to solve this problem (I am a new Ubuntu user)

System details:

> intel i5 processor, 4GB ram, OS: Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that your user is in the `vboxuser` group. To do this run the following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER
```

then force the VirtualBox Module compilation by running following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

If the above command fails, use:

```
sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
```

then try to restart virtualBox from command line

```
/usr/bin/VirtualBox restart
```

Comment: After running the second command it said that dkms was not found: I tried removing and reinstalling dkms but got an error saying that package operation failed

Comment: Did you use `sudo` with reinstalling?

Comment: I reinstalled it from ubuntu software centre, not from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same prompt. I went to try and restart VirtualBox from my personal user as many posts suggested and that failed as well. The error I got for that was:

> Failed to create the VirtualBox COM object

With the following detailed message:

> NS_BASE_STREAM_WOULD_BLOCK

For me the issue was I could only start VirtualBox as root because the `.VirtualBox/` folder in my home directory was owned by **root** and not by my user. To fix it I simply changed the ownership of the folder via:

```
sudo chown <user> .VirtualBox/
```

Now both VirtualBox and Genymotion are working properly. Credit goes this forum post: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=191572

Env info:
**Ubuntu** - 12.04.5 LTS
**VirtualBox** - 5.0.20r106931
**CPU** - Intel i3 M 350 @ 2.27GHz